# Split values into separate Arrays based on keys in a Hash?

Tags: ruby

I have some thing like this

```
[
  {
    "key": "55ffee8b6a617960010e0000",
    "doc_count": 1
   },
    {
     "key": "55fff0376a61794e190f0000",
     "doc_count": 1
    },
    {
     "key": "55fff0dd6a61794e191f0000",
     "doc_count": 1
    }
]
```

i want to separate `:key` values and `:doc_count` values into separate arrays like

```
["55ffee8b6a617960010e0000", "55fff0376a61794e190f0000", "55fff0dd6a61794e191f0000"]
```

and like `[1,1,1]`. How to achieve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [transpose](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-transpose) here:

```
keys, doc_counts = array_of_hashes.map(&:values).transpose
```

As `D-side` points out this relies on the ordering of the keys being the same for each hash. If you cannot ensure this (for instance your data is being created via an API) you would have to perform the additional step of sorting the hash's keys. That would look something like:

```
keys, doc_counts = array_of_hashes.map{|h| Hash[h.sort].values }.transpose
```

In either case you'll end up with something like:

```
keys # => ["55ffee8b6a617960010e0000", "55fff0376a61794e190f0000", "55fff0dd6a61794e191f0000"]
doc_counts # => [1, 1, 1]
```

Comment: Be mindful though that it relies on the order of keys inside the hash. If, say, lines 3-4 were swapped the result would be different.

Answer (score 2):

You can use some of these

```
a = [
  {
    "key" => "55ffee8b6a617960010e0000",
    "doc_count" => 1
  },
  {
    "key" => "55fff0376a61794e190f0000",
    "doc_count" => 1
  },
  {
    "key" => "55fff0dd6a61794e191f0000",
    "doc_count" => 1
  }
]
```

1.

```
hash = Hash[a.map { |h| [h["key"], h["doc_count"]] }]
hash.keys
hash.values
```

2.

```
exp = Hash.new { |k, v| k[v] = [] }
a.map { |h| h.each { |k, v| exp[k] << v } }
```

3.

```
hash = a.each_with_object({}) { |arr_h, h| h[arr_h["key"]] = arr_h["doc_count"] }
hash.keys
hash.values
```

Answer (score 0):

You could iterate and assign it to new arrays `doc_counts` and `keys`.

```
array = [{"key"=>"55ffee8b6a617960010e0000", "doc_count"=>1}, {"key"=>"55fff0376a61794e190f0000", "doc_count"=>1}, {"key"=>"55fff0dd6a61794e191f0000", "doc_count"=>1}]
doc_counts, keys = [],[]
array.each do |a|
    doc_counts << a["doc_count"]
    keys << a["key"]
end
```

Result

```
>> doc_counts
=> [1, 1, 1]
>> keys
=> ["55ffee8b6a617960010e0000", "55fff0376a61794e190f0000", "55fff0dd6a61794e191f0000"]
```

**Or**

```
doc_counts = []
keys = array.map do |a|
    doc_counts << a["doc_count"]
    a["key"]
end
```

Comment: With out creating new arrays `doc_counts, keys = [],[]` is it possible to do??

Comment: Evidently, you need two new arrays as a result. You could also use `map!` to change your input array itself. But again you need to create another array to accommodate other set of values.